Shortest path in a Graph by reducing the Weight of multiple edges by half
Given a directed graph with positive edge weights, a source vertex, a destination vertex, and a integer M (M < 10), find the shortest path from the source to the destination. The twist is that M discounts are available, which can halve the weight of an edge. Each discount can be used only once. What is the shortest path that utilizes these discounts optimally?"
I tried the brute force recursive approach, but it may not be efficient for larger graphs. I am looking for a more efficient algorithm to solve this problem.

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

It's possible to compute the shortest path with discounts by creating a new graph that is (m+1) times bigger than the original one.
What you need to do is to "multiply" your graph, you need M+1 of them (one if no discount was used, one if one discount was used ... one if m discounts were used). So you now have M+1 graphs, let's connect them to each other.
For each edge in your original graph between v and v', with cost w, create an edge between v in the i_th graph and v' in the i+1_th graph, with cost w/2 ; and an edge between v in the i_th graph and v in the i+1_th graph of cost 0 (to represent the fact that we may not need to use all discounts)
Then compute the shortest path between the source vertex of the 0th graph to the destination vertex of the M_th graph.
The complexity is still "the same", we're still running a shortest path, but on a graph that is (m+1) times bigger.

You can still use Dijkstra's algorithm, but instead of storing the minimum distance to each vertex, store the minimum distance to each vertex for each possible number of discounts used. The state thus contains both the current vertex and the number of discounts used on the path from the source vertex to the current one.
At the end, consider the optimal distances to the destination vertex for each possible number of discounts and take the minimum one.
Example implementation in C++:
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
struct Edge {
    int to, weight;
};
int solve(int nodes, int source, int dest, std::vector<std::vector<Edge>>& adj, int maxDiscounts) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> dist(nodes, std::vector<int>(maxDiscounts + 1, 1e9 /* larger than any possible path */));
    struct State {
        int distance, node, discounts;
    };
    std::priority_queue<State, std::vector<State>,
        decltype([](const auto& s1, const auto& s2){return s1.distance > s2.distance;})> pq;
    pq.emplace(dist[source][0] = 0, source, 0);
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        auto curr = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if (dist[curr.node][curr.discounts] == curr.distance)
            for (auto [nextNode, weight] : adj[curr.node]) {
                if (curr.distance + weight < dist[nextNode][curr.discounts])
                    pq.emplace(dist[nextNode][curr.discounts] = curr.distance + weight, nextNode, curr.discounts);
                if (curr.discounts < maxDiscounts && curr.distance + weight / 2 < dist[nextNode][curr.discounts + 1])
                    pq.emplace(dist[nextNode][curr.discounts + 1] = curr.distance + weight / 2, nextNode, curr.discounts + 1);
            }
    }
    return std::ranges::min(dist[dest]);
}


But the problem is dijkstra is a greedy algorithm. Lets say I have a node B in the priority queue. If you want an extra state for discount then you have two node B, one with a discount and one without.  Essentially becoming the same as exponential complexity.

@AnirbanSaha No, you at most have 10 useful copies of each node (it's not with discount and without discount, but how many discounts have been used). That is not exponential.

Okay.. but how many discounts have been used is not a straightforward decision. Lets say I start with source node. And i add to my priority queue 4 nodes. Now each 4 nodes there is a decision to be made. Do i apply a discount or not.  I cannot take the smallest edge node. Because it can vary because of the discount later on.

@AnirbanSaha I see you have misunderstood the algorithm. Let dist[u][d] denote the minimum distance to get to node u using d discounts (all set to infinity at the start except dist[source][0] = 1). Then when your current state is (u, d), for any adjacent node v, check if dist[u][d] + edgeWeight < dist[v][d]. If so, update dist[v][d] and add the new state (v, d) to the queue. Then, also try with a discount if d < M, so check if dist[u][d] + edgeWeight / 2 < dist[v][d + 1]. Similarly, if that is the case, update dist[v][d + 1] and add the state (v, d+1) to the queue.

I can provide code later if you want more details; just let me know what language you use.

Okay.. that part i understood. On what basis will the priority queue work ? On the smallest distance and if there is a match then the smallest number of discounts?  And i use c++

@AnirbanSaha Same as normal Dijkstra's: sort by distance.

@AnirbanSaha I've provided an implementation of this solution in C++.


Find the shortest path using Dijkstra
LOOP for M times

Find the longest hop in the path
Halve the longest hop and update
ENDLOOP over M




This I did try. It wont work. Imagine one graph path with edge weights 6 , 8 , 10 and  20, 2 , 1 . M is 2.

Why not?  The first loop will give a path 6, 8, 10, 10.  The second loop will give 6, 8, 5, 10.

This I did try. It wont work. Imagine one graph path with edge weights 5,6,4,5,2,1 and other path as 20, 2 , 2. M is 1.  Here the dijkstra will give path as 5, 6, 4,5, 2, 1 and using 1 discounts we will get 5,3,4,5,2,1=20. The right answer would have been 10,2,2= 14.

If you want to handle those corner cases, then use Yen's algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm ) to get all the paths between two points, and then try the M loop one each path to find the very best.  I doubt it is worth the effort - Dijsktra will give the best path in most cases, and a decent path always.

@ravenspoint It is trivial to modify Dijkstra's algorithm to solve this problem. It takes very little effort; there is no need to reach for marginally related algorithms.
